# LNK2005 class X already defined in Y.obj

Tags: c++, linker, allocator

I have a starter project and I need to write a custom allocator and diagnostic tools for it. I made a class `Class` in which I have 2 methods for the custom allocator `void alloc()` `void dealloc()` and for the diagnostic tools `void evaluate()`.
Now, I declared an object `test` of type `Class` in `CustomAllocator.h` and use the 2 methods to allocate and deallocate memory with no problems. But when I try to call the `evaluate()` method in `CustomAllocatorTest.cpp` I got the linker error `class Class test(?test@@3VClass@@A) already defined in CustomAllocatorTest.obj` and `LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found`.

Class.h

```
#pragma once
class Class
{
public:
    void alloc() { std::cout << "alloc"; }
    void dealloc() { std::cout << "dealloc"; }
    void evaluate() { std::cout << "evaluate"; }
};
```

CustomAllocator.h

```
#ifndef _CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_
#define _CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Class.h"
Class test;

#endif  // _CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_
```

CustomAllocator.cpp (#include "stdafx.h" includes "CustomAllocator.h")

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  test.evaluate();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: At StackOverflow the code and errors need to be part of the question and must be in text. The main purpose of a question is to help future readers with the same problem years from now.

Comment: I understand I will try to edit it and add all the classes but don't know if it will help future readers since I have pretty specific things in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your file `CustomAllocator.h` you declare `test` in global scope :

```
#ifndef _CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_
#define _CUSTOM_ALLOCATOR_H_
#include "Class.h"

Class test; // <-- Declaration of test 

#endif
```

But your `CustomAllocator.h` is included many times, in many places (in `UseCustomAllocator.h` and `CustomAllocator.cpp`) which will generate an `already defined` error for `test` variable.

Please see how to declare externe globale variable here [#pragma once doesn't prevent multiple variable definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422872/pragma-once-doesnt-prevent-multiple-variable-definitions)

Comment: Ah, I understand so `Class test;`  will get declared many times in a lot of files. I tried to follow advice in the link and declare the `Class test;` in the `CustomAllocator.cpp` and `extern Class test;` in `CustomAllocator.h` and now I get the following error `unresolved external symbol "class Class test"(?test@@3VClass@@A)`. The object should be included only once and seen in the other files since the `CustomAllocator.h` is included.

Comment: if you `extern Class test;` in a header you need `Class test;` in some translation unit (source file).

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu as explained by @drescherjm, you must write `Class test;` (without keyword `extern`) in a `CPP` file. You can do it in your `CustomAllocatorTest.cpp` for exemple. and in `CustomAllocator.h` you write `extern Class test;` hope this will help you

Comment: That's what I'm saying I used `extern Class text;` in the header `CustomAllocator.h` and `Class test;` in `CustomAllocator.cpp` and I get the above error. Tried doing what Landstalker said which is pretty similar to what I did and got the same above error.

Comment: If you get the same error do a clean build. Files compiled before the change may have not been recompiled after.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu I did the same test now, and it works for me.

Comment: I don't understand why, but I keep getting the error, I can't get rid of it. I even downloaded again the project that I posted on github and did the changes with `extern Class text;` to the `CustomAllocator.h` and `Class test;` to `CustomAllocator.cpp` and then compiled it and still get the same thing. Any idea what I might be doing wrong ? Don't know if it's relevant but I'm using VS19.

Comment: ***Any idea what I might be doing wrong ?*** No it should work. Unless you are creating a dll. If the library is a dll you are not handling the export / import at all.

Comment: What's the problem if it's a dll? How should I handle it so it works? I'm only supposed to write the custom allocator and the diagnostics tools, I don't really know about handling the export/import

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu, try to download project, extract it, create a NEW EXEC project in visual studio, copy .h  and .cpp of GIT project to new project folder, Add all copied files : add existing items in Vs option, add  extern declaration, and see if OK

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538134/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-with-dllexport)

Comment: I finally managed to understand at least a little better the .dll files and how to handle the export functions. I saw there are several methods, managed to do it by making an EXPORTS statement in the DEF file). I still have so much more to learn and study... Thanks a lot to both of you for spending so much time helping me and it really solved my problem. I really appreciate your help, I will edit the question when I've got time and add the code.